# hive - how to select top N elements for each match

Tags: hive, hiveql

Please consider a hive table - TableA as mentioned below.

This basic SQL syntax works fine when we want to get "all" the rows that matches the condition in the where clause. I want to limit the returned rows to a number - say N - for each of the matches of where clause.

Let me explain with an example:

(1)
Consider this table:

```
TableA
c1 c2
1.  a
1   b 
1   c 
2.  d
2.  e
2.  f
```

(2) Consider this query:

```
SELECT c1, c2 
FROM TableA 
WHERE c1 in (1,2)
```

(3) As you can imagine, it would produce this result:

```
Actual Results:
c1 c2
1.  a
1   b 
1   c  
2.  d
2.  e
2.  f
```

(4)
Desired Result:

```
c1 c2
1.  a
1   b   
2.  d
2.  e
```

Question: How do I modify the query in #2) to get the desired output mention in #4).

Answer (score 1):

Only 2 values for c1

```
SELECT c1, c2 FROM TableA WHERE c1 = 1 ORDER BY c2 LIMIT 2
UNION ALL
SELECT c1, c2 FROM TableA WHERE c1 = 2 ORDER BY c2 LIMIT 2
```

More than 2 values, use `rank()`

```
select c1,c2 from 
(
    select c1,c2,rank() over (partition by c1 order by c2) as rank 
    from TableA 
) t 
where rank < 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number` function to do this.

```
select c1,c2
from (SELECT c1, c2, row_number() over(partition by c1 order by c2) as rnum 
      FROM TableA
      --add a where clause as needed
     ) t 
where rnum <= 2
```